# how does the certificate distributed by the CA work?

Tags: encryption, gnupg, pgp

I generally wanted to know how a certificate works, I mean a certificate distributed by the Certificate Authority to identify the identity of a sender.

How does it work?

Can you use simple and easily understandable words? Thank you

Comment: It is not clear for me what exactly in the many information on the internet (like [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_certificate)) is too hard for you too understand. It is unclear what kind of knowledge you possess, i.e. how simplified the explanation should be. It is also not clear what should be covered by the explanation, since digital certificates can be a very broad topic. So please be more specific in what you ask.

Comment: First tell us what you have read. Have you read at leas [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure)? What was not clear there? Until you show any efforts I suggest to **close** this question.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you already know, or are confused by, so this is a pretty broad answer. Feel free to request clarification, but you should also try looking up any terms or concepts you're not familiar with. Cryptography uses lots of terms, like "key" and "signature", that are related to but not the same as their everyday uses. I'm going to try to write this in a conversational style and define terms when they might be confusing or unfamiliar, but at the end of the day, it's not a simple process and I'll need to omit a lot of technical detail to keep the length at all reasonable.

---

The primary purpose of a cryptographic certificate is to associate - in a trustworthy method - an identity (could be a person, a company, a domain, a specific computer... etc.) and an asymmetric **cryptographic public key** (such as an RSA or ECDSA public key). The public key always has an associated private key (which is not part of the certificate; everything in the cert is public information) that the identified party - the **Subject** of the certificate - holds onto and can use to sign (and sometimes to decrypt) data. That private key is never shared with anybody, nor can it be deduced from the public key, nevertheless there is only one private key for a given public key.

In addition to these two critical pieces of information (a single certificate may contain multiple subjects, such as both StackOverflow.com and *.StackExchange.com; the public key information contains both the public key's actual binary bits and information about the key such as what algorithm it's for), certificates also contain data about the certificate itself (when it's valid, and for what uses), and information about the **Issuer** (typically a CA) of the certificate, including the issuer's **Signature** of all the other data in the certificate. A cryptographic signature is a small blob of binary data (bits) generated from an arbitrary-length blob of binary data (in this case, the rest of the certificate) and a private key (in the case, the private key of the certificate authority who issued the certificate).

Obtaining a certificate generally involves first creating a public/private key pair. The public key is put into a Certificate Signing Request (CSR), which also contains your identity. The CSR is submitted to the CA, who is supposed to verify (in some way; the details depend on the type and quality of the certificate) that the submitter in fact is (or owns) the entity named in the Subject field of the CSR. Once the CA has verified this, they can fill out the non-signature parts of the certificate (using info from the CSR, plus making sure that the certificate won't be valid for too long or usable for things the CA doesn't agree to such as being a CA itself), and then sign the certificate-to-be using their private key. The resulting signature is combined with that data to become the actual certificate, which the CA then sends back to the requester.

Since a cryptographic signature can be verified using its issuer's public key (which is publicly available, in the issuer's own certificate), and because a verifiable signature can only be created using a private key (which is never shared, and can't be feasibly obtained from the public key), the signature establishes a *transitive trust* between the issuer of the certificate and the subject of it. *If* the certificate's signature is valid, and *if* you trust the issuer to have done their due diligence to verify the identity of the subject before issuing this certificate, then you can trust that the public key in the certificate belongs to the cert's subject.

Once you've established the connection between the cert's subject and the public key, you can determine whether any individual entity (such as a server you want to connect to) is the identified subject by testing whether they hold the private key corresponding to the cert's public key. This is done by making them sign some data, and seeing if the data's signature can be validated using the public key from the cert. (For some algorithms, you could instead encrypt some data using the public key, and see if they can decrypt it.) These operations are built into the handshake performed during establishment of a TLS or SSH connection. The exact details of how you do this securely (such that you neither use them as an "oracle" that will sign or decrypt arbitrary data for you, nor allow them to replay data they've seen before without themselves having the private key) is generally done using cryptographic hash algorithms or key-exchange algorithms, the details of which are not really relevant to this question.

So, that's how you tie a CA (which verifies a subject's identity before signing their Certificate Signing Request and turning a CSR into a certificate) to a Subject (identity), and a Subject to a Public Key, and a Public Key to an actual entity. But how do you determine what CA signatures to trust? After all, anybody can sign a certificate - all you need is a private key, which is easy to generate - so how do you know if the signer (Issuer) is trustworthy? Well, you can check their own certificate, and see if it's valid and issued by a trusted party, but that just kicks the problem up a level. At some point, you need a **Root of Trust**, a list of CAs (and their public keys) that you trust to issue certificates. Every desktop or server operating system (and most embedded ones) include a list of trusted CA certificates. Some programs (such as those from Mozilla) also supply their own list of trusted CA certificates rather than using the system-wide list. If the chain of valid signatures (where the links are between a cert's issuer and the issuer of the CA's cert) terminates in a certificate that's in the Root of Trust, then you can trust the certificate.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply, or is there a little more, and I also like the word PGP, which I would like to say: do you really want this certificate, how can you "sell" to another person? Basically I did this

Comment: PGP does not use CAs, or the Public Key Infrastructure (PKI) in general. While you *can* distribute a PGP public key in an X.509 certificate, that's uncommon; usually they use their own format which, among other things, supports a large number of signatures. PGP doesn't use a trusted root (of CAs), it instead has a "web of trust" where you explicitly trust individuals, and implicitly trust the keys of anybody whose key is signed by them. To convince somebody to accept your PGP key, you usually either prove your identity in person, or get a third party (trusted by the other person) to sign it.

Comment: Are you telling me that PGP doesn't use any certificates? Can't add certificate to PGP-encrypted message?
How do I know that the person I am talking to is really you and not someone who takes over or does a man in the middle attack?

Comment: PGP does not, in general, use certificates (as I said, it *could*, but that's abnormal). I also explained how you know what keys are trusted (at least in theory): The "web of trust", where if A meets B and gets B's public key, they can sign it, and then if B sends that signed key to C, and C trusts A (and knows A's public key, to verify the signature on B's key), then C has reason to trust that the key they received did, in fact, come from B. There are other methods (e.g. keybase.io is a bit like a CA for PGP, etc.) but that's the default for PGP/GPG.